# firebase item deletion throwing array index out of bound exception

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app where users can add item from home fragment to wishlist fragment by tapping on the heart icon. now when i am trying to delete the wishlist items from home fragment it is throwing array index out of bound exception, i am confuse why this is happening please guide me how can i solve this problem?

this is image

[image: check the image here]

So i am writing this code from the homeAdapter of Home Fragment to delete that particular item from wishlist fragment when user tap the heart icon from home fragment

```
 public void deleteData(int position)
{


    wishlistModels = new ArrayList<>();

    //CODE TO GET THE CURRENT USERS WISHLIST DETAILS
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    DocumentReference uidRef =  firebaseFirestore.collection("Wishlist_Details").document(auth.getUid());
    CollectionReference wishlistDetaialRef = uidRef.collection("added_wishlist");

    wishlistDetaialRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

            for (DocumentSnapshot snapshots : value.getDocuments())
            {
               WishlistModel wishlistModelobj = snapshots.toObject(WishlistModel.class);
                    wishlistModels.add(wishlistModelobj);

            }

            wishlistDetaialRef.document(wishlistModels.get(position).getId()).delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "wishlist item removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


                            Toast.makeText(context, "data deletion failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

        }
    });


}
```

**Image of my firebase datastructure**

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the wishlistModels list actually have anything inside before calling the wishlistModels.get(position)?

Comment: so it deleted the very first item's data in the recyclerview but after that it throws the exception

Comment: That's most likely happening because of the addition of the snapshot listener. However, if you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: i dont know kotlin sir please explain in java